# Creating edges between nodes using multiple features/variables

Tags: python, r, networkx

I am trying to create a network that links nodes that share at least a feature, not just "from" and "to" columns. I can do this either in Python or R.

For example, I have transactions data that includes email, phone number, document id, and city. I would like to be able to link all transactions (nodes) that share at least one of the previously mentioned features.

Thanks

Edit:

In the picture we have 3 different "groups" that should be all in the same "group" or "network". Since John and Julian share favorite color, John and Paul city, and Jessica and John year of birth, they are all in group 1. Sean is alone because he does not share any attribute and Tina and Martin share city.

[Network dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfxbB.png)

Comment: can you provide a minimal example of data?

Comment: I meant a reproducible example that can be copied, not an image ;)

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume each transaction is a vector of values in which each entry corresponds to a specific feature. Then a simple pseudo-code I would use for this task is:

```
for transaction_1 in transactions:
    for transaction_2 in transactions:
        if any((transaction_1 - transaction_2) == 0):
            create_edge(transaction_1, transation_2)
```